# How to set colors for buttons on slack using slack API

Tags: node.js, slack-api

I'm trying to set other styles for slack buttons besides the default 3:

```
- primary (green)
- danger (red)
- default (grey)
```

I would like to set other colors for the buttons for example `orange`.

I'm aware that it's possible to set custom colors for attachments by specifying hexcodes.

**Is there a way to specify custom colors for slack buttons?**

Here's what I tried:

```
{
    "text": "Please rate this trip.",
    "attachments": [
        {
            "callback_id": "rate_trip",
            "color": "#3AA3E3",
            "attachment_type": "default",
            "actions": [
                {
                    "name": "yes",
                    "text": "yes :thumbsup:",
                    "type": "button",
                    "value": "yes",
                    "style": "primary"
                },
                {
                    "name": "no",
                    "text": "no :thumbsdown:",
                    "type": "button",
                    "value": "no",
                    "style": "danger"
                },
   // I'd like to make the style for this to be orange but it defaults to grey.
                {
                    "name": "maybe",
                    "text": "maybe :neutral_face:",
                    "type": "button",
                    "value": "maybe",
                    "style": "#FFA500",
                    }
                }
            ]
        }
    ]
}
```

Here's a screenshot of the outcome of this code.
[image: ![Sample Screenshot of Styled Buttons]

Comment: . this helped

Answer (score 5, accepted):

No. Slack does not allow you do use custom colors for buttons. As you mentioned you can only use "styles" (in the `style` field) to color a button and are limited to `default`, `primary` and `danger`.

See [here](https://api.slack.com/docs/interactive-message-field-guide#action_fields) for the official documentation on this very topic.

Comment: Thanks for the clarification @Erik Kalkoken.